# Подскажите, пожалуйста, что за обозначение в формуле

Tags: математика, формулы, линейная-алгебра

Наткнулся на такую формулу
[image]

И у меня возник вопрос. Что это за дробь без черточки справа от нормы(так же вроде называется этот двойной модуль)? И почему там 2ды написана 2ка?

Comment: что такое "2ды" и "2ка"?

Comment: @Эникейщик Человек сэкономил массу времени, сократив "дважды" и "двойка"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Двойные палки слева и справа обозначают норму. Нижний индекс означает что норма *ℓ<sub>2</sub>* - то есть все компоненты вектора нужно возвести в квадрат, сложить, из суммы извлечь корень квадратный. Верхний индекс - не индекс, а степень. Квадрат корня означает что просто не нужно извлекать корень.

*||V||<sub>2</sub><sup>2</sup> = V<sub>1</sub><sup>2</sup> + V<sub>2</sub><sup>2</sup> + V<sub>3</sub><sup>2</sup> + ...*.